# How to show a HashMap as empty {} instead of null

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a HashMap object which will be stored in NoSQL database. When it has entries, it would look like:

"input":{"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2" }

If this "input" does not exist in the db, I want "input":{} to be shown in response instead of "input":null. What is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize it into an empty HashMap by default. If the input value is present set it. Otherwise keep it as the default.

```
Map<String, String> input = Collections.emptyMap();
```

Notice that the use of static factory methods is generally preferred to constructors.

Comment: Thanks, this helped in my case

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your map to a non-null instance. If it is empty, you may assign to `Collections.emptyMap()`, which returns an empty map (immutable).  This map is serializable.

```
map = Collections.emptyMap();
```

Instantiating a new HashMap every time will unnecessarily allocate memory in your JVM and hence increase load on GC

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had to create a new HashMap for the case I had!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both your key and value are of type String, in your application, set a condition that if input-not-exist set result as or directly return `new HashMap<String,String>()`